# summarize dataframe on multiple variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have below mentioned dataframe:

```
ID        Date            Status         Category
TR-1      2018-01-10      Passed         A
TR-2      2018-01-09      Passed         B
TR-3      2018-01-09      Failed         C
TR-3      2018-01-09      Failed         A
TR-4      2018-01-08      Failed         B
TR-5      2018-01-08      Passed         C
TR-5      2018-01-08      Failed         A
TR-6      2018-01-07      Passed         A
```

By utilizing the above given dataframe I want a output format as shown below:

The `Date` should be in descending order and the category sequence should be like C, A and B.

```
Date         count      distinct_count      Passed     Failed
2018-01-10   1          1                   1          0
    A        1          1                   1          0
    B        0          0                   0          0
    C        0          0                   0          0
2018-01-09   3          2                   1          2
    A        1          1                   1          0
    B        1          1                   1          0
    C        1          1                   1          0
```

To derive the above output, I have tried below code but it couldn't work and not able to get expected output.

```
Output<-DF %>%
  group_by(Date=Date,A,B,C) %>%
  summarise(`Count`  = n(),
            `Distinct_count` = n_distinct(ID),
            Passed=sum(Status=='Passed'),
            A=count(category='A'),
            B=count(category='B'),
            C=count(category='C'),
            Failed=sum(Status=='Failed'))
```

Dput:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L
), .Label = c("TR-1", "TR-2", "TR-3", "TR-4", "TR-5", "TR-6"), class = "factor"), 
    Date = structure(c(4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("07/01/2018", 
    "08/01/2018", "09/01/2018", "10/01/2018"), class = "factor"), 
    Status = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Failed", 
    "Passed"), class = "factor"), Category = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"Date", "Status", "Category"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: a ``dput()`` of your initial data frame would be useful for recreating the problem

Comment: The output you propose is untidy, and I think it will be difficult to further work with such output. Are you sure you don't want an output that would be generated by replacing your second line of code by `group_by(Date, Category) %>% `?  You could then summarize a second table grouped only by `Date` in order to get the count of Dates, and `left_join` it to the first one to get an extra column that indicates the count of dates...

Comment: @Luminita: you are suggesting to create two different out put group by date and category and then left_join it???

Comment: Now I looked closer at your `summarise`...I think won't work as you propose. Please add the output of your initial data as suggested by Nutle.

Comment: @Luminita: I have tried but in that what will happens, suppose for any date we don't have any entry of particular category then it wouldn't reflect in output dataframe.

Comment: how does the ID come into play?

Comment: @AndreElrico : to get the count and distinct_count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mixing variables such as `$Date` and `$Category` in one and the same column is a bad idea because, as noted by @Luminata it makes further processing of the data very difficult.

While it is rather unclear what you want to achieve, and therefore any answer must be tentative, here's a solution that *might* get you closer to your goal:

If this is your data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c("TR-1","TR-2", "TR-3", "TR-3", "TR-4", "TR-5", "TR-5", "TR-6"),       
  Date = c("2018-01-10", "2018-01-09", "2018-01-09", "2018-01-09", "2018-01-08", "2018-01-08", "2018-01-08", "2018-01-07"),            
  Status = c("Passed","Passed","Failed","Failed","Failed","Passed","Failed", "Passed"),         
 Category = c("A","B","C","A","B","C","A","A")
)
```

and what you want is separate out data by `$Date`, then why not create a list of separable dataframes for each date using the `by` and `unique` functions:

```
df_list <- by(df, df$Date, function(unique) unique)
df_list
df$Date: 2018-01-07
    ID       Date Status Category
8 TR-6 2018-01-07 Passed        A
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$Date: 2018-01-08
    ID       Date Status Category
5 TR-4 2018-01-08 Failed        B
6 TR-5 2018-01-08 Passed        C
7 TR-5 2018-01-08 Failed        A
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$Date: 2018-01-09
    ID       Date Status Category
2 TR-2 2018-01-09 Passed        B
3 TR-3 2018-01-09 Failed        C
4 TR-3 2018-01-09 Failed        A
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
df$Date: 2018-01-10
    ID       Date Status Category
1 TR-1 2018-01-10 Passed        A
```

Comment: is your suggestion to use `by` an answer?

Comment: Yes, a tentative one. Why?

Answer (score 6):

That was a tough one:

```
# I'm converting some variables to factors to get the "order" right and to fill in missing unobserved values later in dcast.
df1$Category <- factor(df1$Category, levels = unique(df1$Category))
date_lvls    <- as.Date(df1$Date, "%Y-%m-%d") %>% unique %>% sort(decreasing = TRUE) %>% as.character
df1$Date     <- factor(df1$Date, date_lvls)

# lets use data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)

# make a lookup table to deal with the duplicated ID issue. Not sure how to do this elegant
tmp <- dcast.data.table(df1, Date ~ ID, fun.aggregate = length)
tmp <- structure(rowSums(tmp[,-1] == 2), .Names = as.character(unlist(tmp[, 1])))

# precaution! Boilerplate incoming in 3, 2, .. 1
dcast.data.table(df1, Date + Category ~ Status, drop = FALSE)[
    ,`:=`(Failed=+!is.na(Failed), Passed=+!is.na(Passed))][
    , c("count","distinct_count") := rowSums(cbind(Failed,Passed))][
    , Category := as.character(Category)][
    , rbind(
        cbind(Category = as.character(Date[1]), count = sum(count), distinct_count = sum(distinct_count) - tmp[as.character(Date[1])], Passed = sum(Passed), Failed = sum(Failed)),
        .SD
       , fill = TRUE), by = Date][
    , Date := NULL ][]
```

result:

```
 #     Category count distinct_count Passed Failed
 #1: 2018-01-10     1              1      1      0
 #2:          A     1              1      1      0
 #3:          B     0              0      0      0
 #4:          C     0              0      0      0
 #5: 2018-01-09     3              2      1      2
 #6:          A     1              1      0      1
 #7:          B     1              1      1      0
 #8:          C     1              1      0      1
 #9: 2018-01-08     3              2      1      2
#10:          A     1              1      0      1
#11:          B     1              1      0      1
#12:          C     1              1      1      0
#13: 2018-01-07     1              1      1      0
#14:          A     1              1      1      0
#15:          B     0              0      0      0
#16:          C     0              0      0      0
```

---

data:

```
df1<-
structure(list(ID = c("TR-1", "TR-2", "TR-3", "TR-3", "TR-4", 
"TR-5", "TR-5", "TR-6"), Date = c("2018-01-10", "2018-01-09", 
"2018-01-09", "2018-01-09", "2018-01-08", "2018-01-08", "2018-01-08", 
"2018-01-07"), Status = c("Passed", "Passed", "Failed", "Failed", 
"Failed", "Passed", "Failed", "Passed"), Category = c("A", "B", 
"C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "A")), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

---

please note:

- please run every line of code one after another. For this you can close every **ENDING** open bracket and run the line till the end: e.g.

  1. run : `dcast.data.table(df1, Date + Category ~ Status, drop = FALSE)[]`
  2. run : `dcast.data.table(df1, Date + Category ~ Status, drop = FALSE)[
     ,`:=`(Failed=+!is.na(Failed), Passed=+!is.na(Passed))][]`
  3. ... till the end
  4. if then anything is unclear please ask me about this specific thing.

Comment: Getting error `Using 'Category' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override`

Comment: Its not an error its a warning. You can explicity set value.var = "Category"

Comment: Now getting `Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'` Error :(

Comment: again. its NOT an error its a warning. you got that one also before.

Comment: Still getting the same error `Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'`

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure that there must be a more elegant solution, but using `tidyverse` you can do:

```
bind_rows(df %>%
           arrange(Date) %>%
           group_by(Date, Category) %>%
           summarise(count = n(),
                     distinct_count = n_distinct(ID),
                     passed = length(Status[Status == "Passed"]),
                     failed = length(Status[Status == "Failed"])) %>% 
           complete(Category) %>% 
           mutate_all(funs(coalesce(., 0L))) %>%
           ungroup() %>%
           mutate(Date = Category,
                  date_id = gl(nrow(.)/3, 3)) %>%
           select(-Category), df %>%
           arrange(Date) %>%
           group_by(Date) %>%
           summarise(count = n(),
                     distinct_count = n_distinct(ID),
                     passed = length(Status[Status == "Passed"]),
                     failed = length(Status[Status == "Failed"])) %>%
           mutate(date_id = gl(nrow(.), 1))) %>%
 arrange(date_id, Date)

   Date       count distinct_count passed failed date_id
   <chr>      <int>          <int>  <int>  <int> <fct>  
 1 07/01/2018     1              1      1      0 1      
 2 A              1              1      1      0 1      
 3 B              0              0      0      0 1      
 4 C              0              0      0      0 1      
 5 08/01/2018     3              2      1      2 2      
 6 A              1              1      0      1 2      
 7 B              1              1      0      1 2      
 8 C              1              1      1      0 2      
 9 09/01/2018     3              2      1      2 3      
10 A              1              1      0      1 3      
11 B              1              1      1      0 3      
12 C              1              1      0      1 3      
13 10/01/2018     1              1      1      0 4      
14 A              1              1      1      0 4      
15 B              0              0      0      0 4      
16 C              0              0      0      0 4
```

First, it creates a df with the count, the distinct_count, the passed and the failed column based on "Date" and "Category". Second, by using `complete()` it generates all levels in "Category" and then `coalesce()` fill the non-existent levels with 0. Third, it creates a second df with the count, the distinct_count, the passed and the failed column based on just "Date". Finally, it combines the two dfs by rows.

Sample data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "ID        Date            Status         Category
TR-1      2018-01-10      Passed         A
                 TR-2      2018-01-09      Passed         B
                 TR-3      2018-01-09      Failed         C
                 TR-3      2018-01-09      Failed         A
                 TR-4      2018-01-08      Failed         B
                 TR-5      2018-01-08      Passed         C
                 TR-5      2018-01-08      Failed         A
                 TR-6      2018-01-07      Passed         A", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: @tmfnk: Thanks, but I want to keep category A, B and C constant for all the date, irrespective of if the entry available of that category on that particular date, If category not available the value would be 0.

Comment: Getting error like `Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : 
  Argument 2 must be type character, not integer` though all the columns are in character class

Comment: I added sample data to my post. Does it work with that?

Comment: Yes, on sample data its working properly. but I'm getting this error on this line : `dplyr::mutate_all(funs(coalesce(., 0L)))`

Comment: What about `mutate_at(3:6, funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .)))`?

Comment: Now its showing `Error in eval(substitute(expr), envir, enclos) : object 'NA' not found`

Comment: Strange. It works with my sample data and also with your `dput()` data. Maybe try to start a fresh R session. Or update your `tidyverse` library.

Comment: And when you run just this part `df %>%
 arrange(Date) %>%
 group_by(Date, Category) %>%
 summarise(count = n(),
           distinct_count = n_distinct(ID),
           passed = length(Status[Status == "Passed"]),
           failed = length(Status[Status == "Failed"])) %>% 
 complete(Category) %>% 
 mutate_at(3:6, funs(ifelse(is.na(.), 0, .))) %>% 
 ungroup() %>%
 mutate(Date = Category,
        date_id = gl(nrow(.)/3, 3)) %>%
 select(-Category)`, does it work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184956/discussion-between-vector-jx-and-tmfmnk).

Answer (score 2):

You could use a mix of `lapply` on the different levels of the two columns you want to use, mixed with `do.call("rbind",x)`, to bring that back as an array.

Something like this:

```
res=do.call("rbind",lapply(levels(DF$Date),function(d)do.call("rbind",lapply(levels(DF$Category),function(c)
                                                                            {
                                                                                tbl=table(DF$Status[DF$Category == c & DF$Date == d])
                                                                                cbind(Date=d,Category=c,count=sum(tbl),distinct_count=sum(tbl>0),t(tbl))
                                                                            }))))
res=as.data.frame(res)
```

I added a few line to the dataset so the input frame should be:

```
DF <- read.table(text =
"fD    Date    Status    Category
TR-1    2018-01-10    Passed    A
TR-2    2018-01-09    Passed    B
TR-3    2018-01-09    Failed    C
TR-4    2018-01-09    Failed    A
TR-5    2018-01-08    Failed    B
TR-6    2018-01-08    Passed    C
TR-7    2018-01-08    Failed    A
TR-8    2018-01-08    Passed    B
TR-9    2018-01-08    Failed    A
TR-10    2018-01-08    Failed    A
TR-11    2018-01-07    Passed    A"
, header = TRUE)
```

The firs line of code will then output:

```
> res
         Date Category count distinct_count Failed Passed
1  2018-01-07        A     1              1      0      1
2  2018-01-07        B     0              0      0      0
3  2018-01-07        C     0              0      0      0
4  2018-01-08        A     3              1      3      0
5  2018-01-08        B     2              2      1      1
6  2018-01-08        C     1              1      0      1
7  2018-01-09        A     1              1      1      0
8  2018-01-09        B     1              1      0      1
9  2018-01-09        C     1              1      1      0
10 2018-01-10        A     1              1      0      1
11 2018-01-10        B     0              0      0      0
12 2018-01-10        C     0              0      0      0
```

Edit: I think I finally guessed what you meant by "distinct count" so I update the answer.

Comment: This answer seems to me the most succinct while still utilizing efficient tools. +1

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, mixing your variables in one column may not be the best idea, but I've done it by simply combining the rows afterwards:

```
 library(tidyr)
 library(dplyr)
 Output <- DF %>%
   group_by(Date, Category) %>%
   summarise('Count'=n(),
             'Distinct_Count'=n_distinct(ID),
             Passed=sum(Status=='Passed'),
             Failed=sum(Status=='Failed')) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   complete(Date, Category, fill=list(Count=0, Distinct_Count=0, Passed=0, Failed=0))


 perDay <- Output %>% 
   group_by(Date) %>%
   summarise('Count'=sum(Count),
             'Distinct_Count'=sum(Distinct_Count),
             Passed=sum(Passed),
             Failed=sum(Failed)) %>%
   arrange(desc(Date))

 Output$indate <- Output$Date
 Output$Date <- Output$Category
 Combined <- bind_rows(lapply(perDay$Date, function(date) {
   rbind(perDay[perDay$Date==date,], Output[Output$indate==date,c(1,3:6)])
 }))
```

The data.frames perDay and Output count values for each category (where necessary completing them), only later are the binded together per day.